# template class creation

Tags: c++, class, templates

can someone look at this code and tell me if I am creating the pointer and object correctly please.

```
int main() 
{
Square<int>* originalSquare = new Square<int>(3, 3);

for(int r = 0; r < originalSquare -> rowSize; r++)
{

    for(int c = 0; c < originalSquare -> colSize; c++)
    {
        int num= 0;
        originalSquare -> setElement(r, c, num);
    }
}

    return 0;
}

//quick_sort function
void quick_sort(Square<int>* square)
{
    //nothing yet.
}
```

I keep getting a access violation error for somer reason... Program works fine before I changed this from stack to heap...

Any help will be greatful.

Thanks

Comment: Works fine for me: http://codepad.org/xfcv61vB  This is not code that shows your problem

Comment: I just hate it when I hear things like *"I changed this from stack to heap"* from programmers who doubt even on the basic of C++. How exactly did you change it *"from stack to heap"*?

Comment: by having: Square<int> originalSquare(x, y); but no quick_sort function calling

Comment: so where does your code differ from what Mooing Duck has put into codepad?

Comment: @b.buchhold editted my code on post. Have a look please.

Comment: Still works fine: http://codepad.org/8LfeIePt  This is not the code that shows your problem.  Although, I would guess Square allocates a dynamically sized array, and setElement sets it?  Can we see your constructor, and the code for setElement?

Comment: @MooingDuck Thanks Mooing Duck. I've checked the constructor as soon as I've read your comment. (I don't know when) But I acturlly deleted my code for creating the array if that makes any sense. I've added it back in and now it works :). Thanks again guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the code that shows your problem. Although, I would guess Square allocates a dynamically sized array, and setElement sets it? Can we see your constructor, and the code for setElement?

Comment: Thanks Mooing Duck. I've checked the constructor as soon as I've read your comment. (I don't know when) But I acturlly deleted my code for creating the array if that makes any sense. I've added it back in and now it works :). Thanks again guys